# How to get the infinitive form of the verb using NLTK (pos tagging)

Tags: python, nltk, part-of-speech

I'm trying to learn natural language processing (of English) using NLTK and Python.
Is there a way to get the infinitive form of the verb during or after POS-tagging.

For example:

- is (VBZ) => to be
- provided (VBN) => to provide
- using (VBG) => to use

Comment: ot a full answer, but I would investigate WordNet (yes, NLTK had WordNet as a download)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Close, you'll need to add the 'to' at the beginning:

```
>>> from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer
>>> lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
>>> lemmatizer.lemmatize('is', 'v')
'be'
>>> lemmatizer.lemmatize('provided', 'v')
'provide'
>>> lemmatizer.lemmatize('using', 'v')
'use'
```

Comment: Do you have some suggestion for other langage like French?

Comment: @mee use `SnowballStemmer("french")`